# GeForce RTX 3060 Ti: "Windows has stopped this device" (Code 43) - Even after total sytem reinstallation

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-11, nvidia

I'm in a bit of a sad situation, at this point. Yesterday, I tried installing nVidia CUDA on my main PC. Ever since, Windows 11 has refused to collaborate with the GeForce RTX 3060 Ti sitting in the machine and instead jumps to use the onboard graphics card.

I tried:

- Rebooting (of course)
- Updating the driver
- Disabling the device and enabling again
- Uninstalling with DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) in safe-mode and with network cable plugged out
- Updating the BIOS

And, most crucially, I now tried **re-installing the system completely**.

In hardware side I:

- Ensured the power plugs to the card are properly inserted (card lights up and is recognized by the system)
- Tried three different output ports
- Tried both HDMI and DP

Still no dice.

I've googled that other people had issues after installing CUDA, but they all (from what I read) manage to solve it by re-installing the graphics card driver.

What did I miss?

When my driver still messes up, even after a full system re-installation, I'm starting to think this could be hardware-related. But what? And how does that coincide with the installation of CUDA?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the issue.

When re-installing the machine it's not (necessarily) enough to use the Factory Reset option in Windows.

I made a new USB key with Windows 11 and ran a clean installation.

I hope others encountering this issue won't have to go through such drastic measures.